# Paypal, Masspay: 10321 - Insufficient funds

Tags: php, curl, paypal, nvp, masspay

I'd like to use Masspay method from Paypal API. I have an account for business in sandbox with balance more than I need to pay. So, I tried to make a cURL request for masspay, like this (just for test):

```
 $url = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";  
 $params = "METHOD=MassPay&VERSION=".urlencode("64.0")."&currencyID=".urlencode("GBP")."&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress&".
           "USER=".urlencode("stroke_1351502951_biz_api1.gmail.com")."&PWD=1351502971&SIGNATURE=".urlencode("AVtOG4sGbXNumu.aVFTqmP5CzdzZA-um-.BsYD-VZyNXmAeWkq1Jqf.S")."&".
           "L_EMAIL0=".urlencode("stroke_1351584447_per@gmail.com")."&L_Amt0=".urlencode("3")."&".
           "L_EMAIL1=".urlencode("stroke_1351584447_per@gmail.com")."&L_Amt1=".urlencode("1").
           "&CURRENCYCODE=".urlencode("GBP");

 $ch = curl_init();  

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

The result I was given is:

> TIMESTAMP=2012-11-16T08:16:55Z&CORRELATIONID=dabb7bd62605b&ACK=Failure&VERSION=64.0&BUILD=4181146&L_ERRORCODE0=10321&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Insufficient
>   funds&L_LONGMESSAGE0=The account does not have sufficient funds to do
>   this masspay&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

I have funds in two currencies: USD and EUR, when I make payment using them everything is good, but when I choose GBR, e.g. API tell's me that I've no sufficient funds. Looking for answer on x.com forum didn't bring me useful actual information. So the question is: Can I use a USD-account for Masspayment in EUR or other currecies or just in USD? And if it is possible, where should I set it?

Thanks.